# How to solve this using using stirling approx?

Tags: approximation, stirling-numbers

I have a relation $log(n!)=\Theta(n\log n)$ .

And i really don't know how to reduce this using using stirling approx. ?

But do know and tried with few logrithmic property  like " Even if its $\log(n^n)$, its equal to $O(nlogn)$ using log property, right? Clearly $\log(n!)$ is < $log(n^n)$. So $log(n!)=\Theta(n\log n)$ "

And i have been to this article too but didn't find any luck. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: Could you clarify what you're looking for?  I'm not really sure what your question is.  The expression $\log(n!) = \Theta(n\log n)$ is a true statement; are you seeking an explanation of what it means?

Answer (score 2):

$n!\sim\sqrt{2n\pi}\cdot(\frac{n}{e})^n$.

Take the logarithm of both sides (noting that $\log(ab)=\log a+\log b$):
$$
\begin{align}
\log(n!)\sim & \log(\sqrt{2\pi})+\log(\sqrt{n})+\log(n^n)-\log(e^n)\\
=&\log(\sqrt{2\pi})+\frac{1}{2}\log{n}+n\log{n}-n\\
=&\Theta(n\log n)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Even though it does not affect the big O notation change n to -n in the second to last line.

Comment: @mtiano I also realized the typo by myself. Thanks anyways.